# UICollectionViewFlowLayout with fixed item width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

How can I tell my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` custom subclass to use a static, fixed item width value?

I would like my delegate to implement a custom method:

```
collectionView:layout:heightForItemAtIndexPath:
```

to return a variable item height, while the width is fixed. The width is calculated upon the collection view bounds and the section inset:

```
width = collectionView.bounds.width - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right
```

I have created a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass, but it gives me, unsurprisingly, a poor performance, so I'm looking forward to subclass the flow layout instead.

And **don't tell me about `UITableView`**. I know it exists.

Comment: Just a guess: Since a flow layout consists of individual cells, you'd have those cells have their size control what you want. In particular, you'd use the delegate's "collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:" for that.

Comment: Implementing `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` is exactly what I **don't** want to do.

Comment: What gives you the idea that there's another solution then? `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` is the most direct - after all, a cell's size is what the layout needs to know in order to be able to determine the widths of the cells. Even the docs explain this.

Comment: I want to create a table-like layout. Width doesn't matter, and the delegate shouldn't worry about it. Only the height is important. That's why I want to create a custom layout. What else don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I ended up by subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout`, thus fixing ald the bad performance issues.

However, if someone eventually comes up with an answer to my question, I will gladly accept it.